# Get a list of product groups through AKENEO PIM's API

Tags: akeneo

I would like to get a list of all my product groups in AKENEO PIM, using the built-in api.

I have been reading the [official documentation](https://api.akeneo.com/api-reference-index.html) carefully but I could not find anything regarding fetching a list of product groups similar to the one you can get in the frontend client under `Settings Tab > Groups`.

Anyone has an idea about a potential workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a workaround : initially I required this data to provide an external system with.

Initially I thought about opening an external endpoint for it (this data is already in the internal API but not in the external API).

But using Akeneo's export functionality ended up being easier :)